# Метод os не видит пробел

Tags: python, ос, python-3.7

Делаю небольшую программу - лаунчер The Sims 4. Использую метод `os`. Вот код:

```
os.system(r'C:\Games\The Sims 4\Game\Bin_LE\TS4.exe')
```

В результате компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

> "C:\Games\The " не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Что не так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
os.system(r'C:\Games\"The Sims 4"\Game\Bin_LE\TS4.exe')
```